# How can an email addressed to somebody else arrive in my inbox?

Tags: email, domain

I recently received an email to my Hotmail account which was addressed to a different email address from my one. The domain it's addressed to is trendytribestexh.store. It's an email which appears to be from PayPal to someone who is not me for an invoice of a large number of New Zealand dollars. At first I assumed that this was some kind of scam, but the next week I then had a strange message from PayPal telling me that my account had been permanently suspended due to an undisclosed 'potential risk'. I have logged into my PayPal accounts and the suspension email is legitimate. I looked back and the email which was addressed to trendytribes does appear to be a legitimate email from PayPal, as far as I can see.

So, there is definitely something strange going on here. My primary question is, how can it be that an email which is not addressed to me, and is even addressed to a completely different domain, can arrive in my inbox?
Secondly, if anybody knows if this could be related to some kind of potential scam or how it might be related to PayPal suspending my account I would also be interested in any information about this.

Comment: Your name wouldn't be listed if BCC-ed. As for paypal issues, you need to directly contact them.

Comment: @Brian oh thankyou, I see that this is literally the definition if BCC, I didn't know that was what it did.

Comment: It's a legitimate use case… on occasion. But not on this occasion. It's a mass-mailout phishing attempt. Learn what they look like & learn not to interact with them at all, unless your mail app has a way of not responding to links in emails; otherwise you give away that you at least read it.

Comment: I'd invest in a spam filter which can ensure any links are not followed. idk a good one for Windows, but this is what they do on my Mac. This one isn't malicious, it's just an advert from a supermarket I actually have an online account with, but it gets dealt with the same way. It doesn't follow any links in the email, so not even the html images will load until I specifically allow it to. The sender is therefore not aware I have interacted with it at all - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BoD9.jpg

Comment: @Tetsujin how do you know it's a phishing email? The sender address is service@intl.paypal.com which is the same address my legit account suspension email came from

Comment: Contact PayPal to determine the reason your account was suspended but it’s not possible for you to receive an email not actually addressed to you. Check the email headers to determine the actual recipient of the email.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yes it does feel free to mark as a duplicate

Comment: "an invoice of a large number of New Zealand dollars" …& some people would just pay it to whatever link it said without even thinking [if you click through there's no doubt at all that it will **look** like PayPal, but little doubt in my mind it will not **be** PayPal.. Learn not to trust this stuff. It can be very expensive if you're not suspicious enough about things. If you ever are in doubt, don't click links in emails, go to your browser & actually type paypal.com

Comment: @Joe - PayPal doesn’t use BCC to send emails to users.

Comment: @Ramhound yes that's what I thought. Then how can you explain the sender address being a legitimate PayPal address?

Comment: Did you look at the *real* address in the headers, or just what it looks like at first glance? Some mailers will show the true address if you hover - this one's *not a bit suspicious, is it?* ;)) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GubWH.png

Comment: @Tetsujin I am certain that the sender address is service@intl.paypal.com, this is in the header and not only in the message.

Comment: Forward the email, with headers intact to phishing@paypal.com & see what they have to say about it. We can't examine it so we can't see what you may or may not have missed.

Comment: @Tetsujin I will do that, thank you for your help

Comment: @Joe - It’s trivial to make it appear to have been sent by PayPal but PayPal doesn’t BCC email recipient nor do they send emails to multiple recipient with regards to account activity. They send mass emails of course per your own individual account settings about their services but never your individual account. Hopefully, you didn’t click on a link, to check your account status, it’s also trivial to create a fake website that looks like PayPal to users who click on links contained within an email they were not expecting.